# How to compare two variable. one is perl variable and another is python variable

Tags: python, perl

I am getting one output from perl subroutine and another output from python function.

I want to compare these two variables so that I can conclude both outputs are same.

ex-python function

```
#!usr/bin/lib/python
import os,sys
def sub(a, b):
   e= a-b
   return e

   #calling function
   p = sub(9,2)
   print "value of P:%s" %p
```

o/p  value of p : 7

perl subroutine---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $average;
sub Average{
   $n = scalar(@_);
   $sum = 0;

   foreach $item (@_){
      $sum += $item;
      }
      $average = $sum / $n;
      return $average;
      }

 #calling subroutine
 $average = Average(11,3);
 print "my avearage : $average";
```

o/p   my avarage: 7

since this is two different language, I am facing problem in comparing p value with average.

Comment: What language is actually doing the comparison as the end step?

Comment: it may be python or perl. anything is fine.

Comment: I am executing all python and perl files in window system.so how can I compare?

Answer (score 3):

Call the programs from the shell, strip off the words before the numbers, and compare them:

```
python_result=$(python_prog)
perl_result=$(perl_prog)
perl_result
if [ "${python_result#*:}" = "${perl_result#*: }" ]
then echo They match
else echo No match
fi
```

Comment: Why not strip using the shell instead of `sed`?  `python_result=${python_result#*:}`

Comment: Good idea, old habits... :)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am doing all comparison in windows machine. pls help.

Comment: You could instead have one of the scripts invoke the other script, and capture its output into a variable. E.g. perl can do `$python_result=\`python_prog\`;`.

Comment: while i am doing likethis , it is saying "illegal declaration of anonymous subroutine at test1.pl".   test1.pl contains function average . and i am calling function sub here.  could you please give the example by taking above 2 subroutines.

Comment: I don't use Windows much, but I suspect `#!/usr/bin/perl` doesn't work there.